# staticmethod not available when init runs

Tags: python, initialization, static-methods

I realised that I cannot call a class' static method from its `__init__` method.

```
class c():

    def __init__(self):
        f()

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print("f called")

c()
```

gives a `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`.

Why is it not able to find the static method?

Comment: Oh man, I am silly. Got it, posting the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because Python is searching for a function called `f` in the global namespace when you reference it like that.

To reference the class' `f` method, you need to make sure Python is looking in the appropriate namespace. Just prepend a `self.`.

```
class c():

    def __init__(self):
        self.f()  # <-

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print("f called")

c()
```

results in

```
f called
```

Comment: You call static method by using `ClassName` and not self, check my answer!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, actually you can do either. A static method means that you don't need `self`, but `self` is not passed into the method if you do use it.

Comment: Ohh got it, but outside the class you need to use ClassName?

Comment: It works fine with `self` and I prefer that for its impliciteness. Is there a reason why the classname should be prefered?

Comment: Yeah, when calling it from outside an instance you need the class name. :)

Comment: Out side is the same as inside: either way use <class>.method() or <instance>.method()

Comment: Thanks @quamrana bugmenot123, I have noted everything mentioned in the comments in my answer above, please have a look at the answer! and upvote it if it looks good :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `f()` is a method of the class, you can either use `c.f()` or `self.f()` to call it

```
class c():

    def __init__(self):
        #Call static method using classname
        c.f()
        #Call static method using self
        self.f()

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print("f called")

c()
```

Then the output will be

```
f called
f called
```

Similarly to call static method outside the class, we can use `ClassName` or `Instance`

```
#Using classname to call f
c.f()

#Using instance to call f
c().f()
```

The output will be

```
f called
f called
```

Comment: Please check if my answer looks good now @quamrana and upvote it if it does :)